Devexpress Xtragrid Multilevel Master-Detail repeat Headers
I am using a Gridcontrol with three levels of views, lets call them shipment, order, position. every shipment can have N orders, every order N positions.
When users now have multiples of each level expanded they very easily loose track, since the values look similar.
As a solution I want to reuse the header row of the orders view. (see badly edited screenshot)

Yellow exists, green is where i want them to be.
I contacted Devexpress support and they answered: this does not work and could not offer a workaround hack, so I'm coming to you.
Group rows i want to avoid because: a) i already have a few of them and b) they are not linked to the columns (afaik)
So i am looking for a way to maybe grab the reader row per view and splice it after each row of that view.
Appreciate you taking the time to read this.
